# A Rails app where the User is also a "something else", not sure how to word this correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, cancan

I am working on a Rails app where the data model involves the following:

- `Companies`, which have_many `Restaurants`
- `Restaurants`, which have_many `Reservations`
- `Customers`, which mave_many `Reservations`

My confusion comes from the fact that there are 3 distinct types of users:

- An employee of the `Company`, who can see an admin dashboard showing data on all of the restaurants that company owns/manages
- The restaurant itself (which will, in theory, have their dashboard open all day, and should be able to log into their own dashboard, but not be able to see any other restaurant's dashboard)
- The customer, who has a UI to make a reservation at a certain restaurant

Should the `Restaurant` be a type of `User`?

Should each restaurant just get it's own standard user-login to access their specific restaurant? If this is the case, would a `Restaurant have_one User`, and I can use something like CanCanCan to restrict Users so that they can only access a `Restaurant` where the `Restaurant's ID == User.restaurant.id`?

This is my first app that addressed atypical `User` types, so I'm at a complete loss on this. Any guidance/best practices on how to address a situation like this would be much appreciated!

Additionally, I would like to use Devise for the User model(s). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, first of all, that it is only ever a User that is actually logging into your website.  A restaurant can't log into a website.  A user who is a representative of the restaurant **can** log in.  Therefore the restaurant should **not** be a type of user.

A better fit is to give your users **roles**, and have one of the roles be "restaurant_manager" or something.  These users would naturally be associated with the restaurant too, so your code could look something like

```
if current_user.role == "restaurant_manager"
  #show extra links for the restaurant admin section
elsif current_user.role == "company_manager"
  #show extra links for the company admin section
```

or something along those lines, and, like you suggest, you make sure that a user can only ever access their own restaurant/company in the restaurant/company admin sections.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. So would the model be set up so that a `Company` `has_many :users` of `role = restaurant_manager`? How can I then segment a company's employees so that a restaurant_manager can't see another restaurant's dashboard, even if they are owned by the same company? Should a `Restaurant` have a many-to-many relationship with `restaurant_managers` through something like `authorized_employee`? There are a bunch of roles, I guess, b/c the company's CEO should be able to access all of the restaurants, but an individual manager should only have access to their own restaurant.

Comment: With objects like restaurants, you may have more than one person with administrative access, a join table (restaurant_users - restaurant_id, user_id, role) would allow you to have a restaurant associated with the user and role.

Comment: @Swards, Thanks, would you think that I would have to have a join table for restaurant_users and company_users, even if the company and the restaurant are already associated (the users may require different access rights)?

Comment: Yes, with something like that, employees can have limited access to all restaurants in a company while managers have complete access to a single restaurant.